# Mac OS X tries to launch jar with Java 1.5 although it needs 1.6

Tags: java, macos

I have a Java project which uses Java 1.6. I package a jar, the manifest simply states the Main-Class.

On the Mac, it fails to start since it tries to use 1.5 for it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:676)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:317)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:280)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:375)
```

Can I specify the 1.6 in the jar or do I need to alter the settings on the Mac?

Comment: What versions of Java have you installed on the Mac (and what version of the OS)?

Comment: I know that there is 1.5 installed, I just assume that there is 1.6 installed as well, just not as first priority. I'll ask what OS X it is.

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  If so, launch it using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) and let that do the run-time version control.

Comment: It has a GUI. I also have a webstart option available, so I will encourage the users to use it then.

Answer (score -1):

Just start it by calling the correct java runtime from a JDK/JRE 6 installation, if you don't want to change default settings (although I would recommend to switch to Java 6).

Comment: No problem with a downvote if my answer is not correct or misleading - but it would have been nice to know why. I still think it might be the right way to explicitely call the java executable from the version needed when executing the desired jar file.